# Since when has Germany allowed naturalization in other EU countries without loss of German citizenship?

Tags: germany, eu, dual-citizenship, german-citizens

Germany now allows its citizens to acquire the citizenship of other EU countries without losing their German citizenship. For how long has this been the case?

Answer (score 4):

Since 28. August 2007, where in Section 25 (1) sentence 2 StAG was added.

---

> **§ 25 Abs. 1 Satz 2 StAG**
>   Der **Verlust nach Satz 1 tritt nicht ein**, wenn ein Deutscher die Staatsangehörigkeit eines anderen Mitgliedstaates der Europäischen Union, der Schweiz oder eines Staates erwirbt, mit dem die Bundesrepublik Deutschland einen völkerrechtlichen Vertrag nach § 12 Abs. 3 abgeschlossen hat.
>
> > **Section 25 (1) sentence 2 StAG**
> >     The **loss under sentence 1 does not arise** if a German acquires the citizenship of another member state of the European Union, Switzerland or a state with which the Federal Republic of Germany has concluded a contract under international law pursuant to § 12 (3).

---

**Sources**:

- [Fassung § 25 StAG a.F. bis 28.08.2007 (geändert durch Artikel 5 G. v. 19.08.2007 BGBl. I S. 1970)](https://www.buzer.de/gesetz/4560/al8339-0.htm)

Comment: Do you know of a list of countries with which there exists such contracts.

Comment: @mic Based on the pdf from this link (dated September 2013) there are none. https://www.bundestag.de/blob/459010/2ef43910c45e17204fb056e3d2537507/wd-3-162-13-pdf-data.pdf